# Tgrub at boot up, how do I fix it?

Tags: partition

I installed Android x86 on a laptop and got it to work fine, until I rebooted. I'm running it as a stand alone and went in and deleted partitions thinking I knew what i was doing. What I do know, I have to reinstall the OS, first creating 2 partitions. That's where I need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot a Live CD/USB with GParted (or any distro which lets you try it with GParted, like Ubuntu/Lubuntu/Xubuntu).
Then with Gparted its easy, you chose the device (sda or sdb, for example), make the partitions you need (for android you will need one primary ext4, if you need more, you can make as many as you want), reboot and use your androidx86 media to boot and install like you did before.

Here you got a tutorial with images in case you don't know how to do it:
http://www.fitzweekly.com/2016/01/how-to-install-android-marshmallow-on.html